# Vue on input text, changes background color for both input fields

Tags: vue.js, dom-events, bootstrap-vue

I am using `bootstrap-vue` to display modal. Once the modal is opened using `OPEN MODAL BUTTON`, it displays two input fields. When I add a text to one of the input field, it changes color on both input fields. Is there a way to change color for the field which consists of datatype only?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <b-modal id="modal-center" ref="modalRef" centered title="DISPLAY MODAL" v-bind:hide-footer="true">
   <b-row class="my-1">
      <b-col sm="11">
       <div v-for="(listings, index) in list2" :key="index">
        <br/>
        <b-form-input v-model="listings.rfidState1" placeholder="insert text" v-on:input="gotText()" :style="isChanged ? { 'background-color': '#33FF90' } : null" ></b-form-input>
       </div>
      </b-col>
  </b-row>

  <br/>

  <b-row>
    <b-col><b-button block variant="info" v-on:click="hidemodal();">UPDATE</b-button></b-col>
    <br/>
   </b-row>

    <br/>

  </b-modal>

  <b-button block v-b-modal.modal-center variant="info">OPEN MODAL</b-button>

</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list2: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false }
    ],

    isChanged: false
  },
  methods: {

    hidemodal(){
        this.$refs['modalRef'].hide()
    },

    gotText(){
        this.isChanged = !this.isChanged;
    }

  }
})
```

Here is my code on `jsfiddle`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/wgr3m6td/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done with a few changes.

First, remove isChanged from your data, and add it as a property to each of your list2 objects, so each object looks like this:

```
{ text: "Your text", done: false, isChanged: false }
```

next, your :style="isChanged ? ", should instead be:

```
:style="listings.isChanged ? "
```

next up, your v-on:input="gotText" should take the index as a parameter like so:

```
v-on:input="gotText(index)"
```

last, your gotText method should receive the index and use it to update isChanged:

```
gotText(index) {
  this.list2[index].isChanged = !this.list2[index].isChanged
}
```

This should answer your question, but if you want some of the behaviour changed ask away.

Edit:
As suggested by n-smits, your data in the vue instance should not be an object, but a function that returns an object like this:

```
data(){
  return {
    list2: [..]
  }
}
```

I recommend that you read his comment to understand why this is necessary.

Comment: On top of that, just a quick snipe on something I've noticed in the question code. Data should be a function which returns an object - otherwise you will be updating it across all components. As an example, try the buttons on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Reusing-Components (the first set of 3 is separated, the second set is not)

Comment: Good catch! Didn't notice this :)